# different stages in bash programming

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash program with different stages like:

```
$stage=1

if [ stage -le 1]; then echo "execute stage 1" fi
if [ stage -le 2]; then echo "execute stage 2" fi
if [ stage -le 3]; then echo "execute stage 3" fi
```

my codes in stages are very computationally expensive. What I want is to execute those stages which are required.

How can I call stage 3 directly and skip stage 1 and stage 2 from command terminal in linux.

Thanks

Comment: Change `-le` to `-eq`? BTW you need whitespace before the closing `]`s

Comment: And how to call this script with stage 3: like the name of the script is stages.sh ?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a case statement for this one. Let's say we create a script called `stage.sh`, then it could be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
        1) echo "stage 1" ;;
        2) echo "stage 2" ;;
        3) echo "stage 3" ;;
        *) echo "unknown stage" ;;
esac
```

What it does is that it takes the first input (`$1`) when called from the command line and matches it with the case statement. Here, running `./stage.sh 1` would display `stage 1`, and `./stage.sh 5` would display `unknown stage` since there is no case match (so it will resort to the `*)` option).